# Backbone JS - updating parent model collection on nested child model change

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a parent model with a collection of child models. For each child model, I want to render a form with the data, then update the parent model when a change happens on any of the forms:

In the parent model view:

```
render: function () {    
    _.each(this.model.get('myChildModelCollection').models, function (myChildModel) {
       var childForm = new ChildFormView({model: myChildModel}) 
       childForm.model.on('change', function () {
              //DO SOMETHING HERE TO UPDATE THE PARENT MODEL COLLECTION
       })
       this.$("#child-list").append(childForm.render().el);
    });
}
```

The change event is getting triggered, but I don't know the correct way to reference the right child model in the parent model collection.

Comment: Sorry - I've been upvoting, but maybe not ticking as much as I should :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really want to set the bindings in your view, you could rewrite your render method as

```
render: function () {
    var parent=this.model, coll=parent.get('myChildModelCollection');

    // Backbone proxies Underscore methods on its collections
    coll.each(function (myChildModel) {
        var childForm = new ChildFormView({model: myChildModel}) 
        this.$("#child-list").append(childForm.render().el);
    });

    coll.on('change', function(model) {
        // do what you have to do with 
        // parent as your parent model,
        // coll as your collection,
        // model set to the modified child 
    });
}
```

Note that such bindings will probably be more effective when controlled either in your parent model or in the collection.

Comment: Big plus one for the proxy - didn't know that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is something that came to my mind:

```
  render: function () { 
        var that = this;   
        _.each(this.model.get('myChildModelCollection').models, function (myChildModel) {
           var childForm = new ChildFormView({model: myChildModel}) 
           childForm.model.on('change', function () {
                that.renderTheCollection();
           })
           this.$("#child-list").append(childForm.render().el);
        });
    }, 
    renderTheCollection : function() {
        _.each(this.model.get('myChildModelCollection').models, function (myChildModel) {
              // Update
        }
     }
```